# Create Array by Dynamic Keys and Values

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am getting a value in string in a variable, i.e

```
let name = 'Vishesh';
let name2 = 'Vishesh2';
```

and an Array i.e

```
let cars = [{carName: "Mercedes"},{carName: "Volvo"},{carName:"BMW"}];
```

Now I want to create an Array where my Key is the name and in value, there should be cars array, i.e

```
Array=[{Vishesh: [{carName: "Mercedes"},{carName: "Volvo"},{carName:"BMW"}]},{Vishesh2: [{carName: "Mercedes"},{carName: "Volvo"},{carName:"BMW"}]}];
```

Comment: What have you tried yet?

Comment: There's always only 2 names?

Comment: let myarray:any[]=[];let obj1:any={};obj1[name]=cars;myarray.push(obj1)

Comment: No name1 and name2 are just an example to show it would be multiple. They are dynamic values so it's uncertain how many names you would get.

Comment: @Eliseo please answer it don't comment.

Comment: Shouldn't your dynamic keys be contained in another array?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
let name = 'Vishesh';
let name2 = 'Vishesh2';
let cars = [{carName: "Mercedes"},{carName: "Volvo"},{carName:"BMW"}];
let array = []

array.push({[name]:cars})
array.push({[name2]:cars})
console.log(array);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can interpolate the names directly into the dictionary construction as a key.

```js
let name = 'Vishesh';
let name2 = 'Vishesh2';
 
console.log([
  {
    [name]: [
      { carName: "Mercedes" },
      { carName: "Volvo" },
      { carName:"BMW" }
    ]
  },
   {
    [name2]: [
      { carName: "Mercedes" },
      { carName: "Volvo" },
      { carName:"BMW" }
    ]
  }
]);
```

But you can do this a bit more dynamically

```js
let name = 'Vishesh';
let name2 = 'Vishesh2';
let cars = [
  { carName: "Mercedes" },
  { carName: "Volvo" },
  { carName:"BMW" }
];

function keyByNames(names, cars) {
  let named = {}
  names.forEach(name => {
    named[name] = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(cars))
  })
  return named
}

console.log(keyByNames([ name, name2 ], cars));
```

Comment: Cool, didn't know you could do that!

Comment: Without dynamic code it was perfect as I wanted but, the Dynamic code is not proper because it is not an Array. @Mathyn Solution for dynamic worked for me as he is using push, So I get in Array.

Answer (score 1):

How about this (assuming it is only two names):

```
let obj1 = {};
obj1[name] = cars;

let obj2 = {};
obj2[name2] = cars;

var array = [obj1, obj2];
```

Do note: both objects reference the same array. Changing the array will therefore 'update' the array in two places (since it is by reference).

If however you want a dynamic set of names your code could look like this:

```
var names = ["Vishesh", "Vishesh2", "Vishesh3"];

var array = [];
for(var i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
    var name = names[i];

    var obj = {};
    obj[name] = cars;

    array.push(obj);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

using reduce function on your array of cars can be solution as well.:

```js
let names = ["Wishes1", "Wishes2", "Wishes3"]

let cars = [{carName: "Mercedes"},{carName: "Volvo"},{carName:"BMW"}];

const withNames = (names) => (currentMapState, currentItem, currentIndex) => {
 currentMapState[names[currentIndex]] = currentItem;
  return currentMapState;
}

console.log(cars.reduce(withNames(names), {}));
```

And bonus is that withNames function is easily testable. Have a nice day.

Comment: Thanks for the help but I wanted it in an Array. Upvoted for your effort.

Comment: Oh, i see. Sorry for that. I will stay with reduce and instead of pushing it to map you can push it to array like this: https://jsfiddle.net/krewilone/5hsaq7eu/

Answer (score 0):

if there is always two names:

```
const Array = [
  { [name]: cars },
  { [name2]: cars }
]
```